# How to display a login page over other contents and remove scrollbar when login page is displayed?

Tags: html, css

I want to pop up the the login page when the login button is clicked.
It should be shown over all the other contents and the scrollbar should disappear too.

Something like this...
[image: Something like this is what I want]

```
        <div class="navButtons">
          <button class="homeButton navButtonOne" href="#login">LOG IN</button>
        </div>
```

On click of the above button, the code below should display.

```
    <div id="login">
      <img src="./logo.png" class="loginLogo">
      <div class="loginForm">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter username">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password">
        <button class="navButtonOne">Login</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

What CSS should I add and to which class/id?
Help me out...

Comment: Generally you remove the scrollbar by adding `overflow: hidden` to the `body` element.  A modal can be created using `position: absolute` and setting `z-index`, but keep in mind that anyone who knows how to use the devtools can remove the login modal/overlay to access the content beneath, so don't use it as security to protect that content.  You can also use the devtools to look at examples on a library like [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) to see how they achieve some of these effects.

Comment: you can look on this example:

https://codepen.io/designcouch/pen/obvKxm

or

https://tympanus.net/Development/ModalWindowEffects/

Ragards